python unittest mocking a custom exception and triggering it
I can't get my custom mock exception to trigger
def exist_on_p4(path, p4):
    """ Checks to see if file exists on p4 """
    try:
        p4.run_files('-e', path)
        return True
    except P4Exception:
        return False

    @mock.patch('module.P4Exception', create=True)
    def test_does_not_exist_on_p4(self, mock_P4Exception):
        mocked_p4 = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_P4Exception.side_effect = Exception('P4Exception')
        mocked_p4.run_files.side_effect = mock_P4Exception()
        mocked_p4.run_files.return_value = None
        self.assertFalse(exist_on_p4('test', mocked_p4))

Trying to get this to return False but i cant seem to get it to work

You don't need to mock the exception for this test.
